# Mvc Core 5 or higher WebGrid using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there any GridView in .net MVC core like below MVC webgrid? which support sorting,filtering using Angularjs.

```
@grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
    headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
    footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
    alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
    selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
    rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
    columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("GRNNo"),
    grid.Column("InvoiceNo"),
    grid.Column("Total",format:(item)=>string.Format("{0:c2}", item.Total)),
    grid.Column("InvoiceDate",format:(item)=>string.Format("{0:d}", item.InvoiceDate)),
    grid.Column(format: (item) => new HtmlString(
        Html.EnActionLink("Details", "Details", "GRNs", new { id = item.ID }, new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" }).ToHtmlString() + " | " +
        Html.EnActionLink((item.IsDeleted == false) ? "Delete" : "Activate", "Delete", "GRNs", new { id = item.ID }, new { @class = (item.IsDeleted == false) ? "glyphicon glyphicon-trash colorred" : "glyphicon glyphicon-open colorspringgreen" }).ToHtmlString()))
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `NonFactors.Grid.Mvc6` NuGet package in .net core, have you considered using it? The following are the usage steps and example.

Install `NonFactors.Grid.Mvc6` Package.

After successful installation, navigate to the following folder (directory):

```
`%UserProfile%\.nuget\packages\nonfactors.grid.mvc6\{version}\content`
```

[image]

Then, copy the `\css\mvc-grid` folder and paste it inside the `wwwroot/css` folder, copy the `\js\mvc-grid` folder and paste it inside the `wwwroot/js` folder, and copy the `\Views\Shared\MvcGrid` folder and paste it inside the `Views/Shared` folder:

[image]

Then add the following in `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<link href="~/css/mvc-grid/mvc-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/js/mvc-grid/mvc-grid.js"></script>
<script>
       [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('mvc-grid'), function (element) {
          new MvcGrid(element);
       });
</script>
```

Send data from controller to view:

```
public IActionResult Index() 
{
    var data = ...;
    //Queryable is required
    return View(data.AsQueryable()) 
}
```

View:

```
@using NonFactors.Mvc.Grid
@*IQueryable is required*@
@model IQueryable<Project.Models.TestModel>

@(Html.Grid(Model).Build(columns =>
        {
            columns.Add(model => model.Id).Titled("ID");
            columns.Add(model => model.Name).Titled("Name").Sortable(false);
            columns.Add(model => model.Age).Titled("Age");
        })
        .Using(GridFilterMode.Header)
        .Empty("No data found")
        .Filterable()
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable(pager =>
        {
            pager.PageSizes = new Dictionary<Int32, String> { { 0, "All" }, { 2, "2" }, { 4, "4" } };
            pager.ShowPageSizes = true;
            pager.PagesToDisplay = 3;
            pager.CurrentPage = 2;
            pager.RowsPerPage = 2;
        })
    )
```

Result:
[image]

For more details, you can refer to [this link](https://mvc-grid.azurewebsites.net/).

Comment: Yes, It was useful to create a nice grid